# Is this legitimate code and why?

Tags: c++

Lets say I have a function that takes a string as a char*

```
void GiveMeFileName(const char* fileName)
```

and I call it like this

```
std::string folderName("C:\\myFolder\\");
GiveMeFileName((folderName + "file.dat").c_str());
```

As far as I can tell its working fine but as to why is a bit shaky in my head.

When I add the const char* to the std:::string, it creates a new string which I call c_str() upon to pass the pointer to the function. Is it possible that after I call the c_str() and it resolves into a pointer, the temporarily created string gets deleted and what I'm passing is in fact a pointer to the remnant of an object and thus could potentially fail?

Comment: It is fine. I don't have reference but the lifetime of the temp string is at end of semi-colon

Comment: Yes, it's fine.  If the values created in a parameter list went away before the function they were passed to finished, that would be pretty worthless.

Comment: Just don't store `fileName` anywhere which outlives `GiveMeFileName`.